# A Geometric view of PCA. Optimization problem formulation and solution

Tags: pca, optimization

I am trying to understand the solution of the optimization problem in geometric PCA. In my lecture notes I have the following:

Given $$\{x_{1}, ..., x_n\}\in\mathbb{R}^{D}$$ we seek a low-dim representation $$\{y_1, ..., y_n\}\in\mathbb{R}^d$$ such that: $$x_i=Uy_i+\epsilon_i\ \ where\ \  U=[u_1, ..., u_d]\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times d}$$
So we have the following optimization problem: 
$$\underset{U,\ \{y_i\}}{min}\underset{i}{\sum}||x_i-Uy_i||^2\ \ s.t.\ U^TU=I_d\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
And following Lagrangian:
$$L=\underset{i}{\sum}||x_i-Uy_i||^2+Tr((I_d-U^TU)\Lambda)\ \ \ \ \ \ (2)\\ where\ \Lambda=\Lambda^T\ is\ a \ matrix\ of\ Langrangian\ multipliers$$
**My first problem** here is that I don't understand the trace representation. Since matrix `U` consists of orthonormal vectors I would write it like this:
$$L=\underset{i}{\sum}||x_i-Uy_i||^2-\underset{i,\ j=1,\  i\neq\ j}{\sum}\lambda_{ij}u_i^Tu_j+\underset{i}{\sum}\lambda_{ii}(1-u_i^Tu_i)\ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

How do I get from `(3)` to `(2)`? I tried to write it with indices of each element in each matrix taking `U` to be `3x2`, but is there an easier way to prove it?

After differentiation with respect to `y` we get:
$$y_i=U^Tx_i$$
Then, in order to optimize over `U` we substitute `y` into (1) and we have:
$$\underset{i}{\sum}||x_i-UU^Tx_i||^2\underset{(*)}{=}\underset{i}{\sum}x_i^T(I_D-UU^T)x_i\underset{(**)}{=}Tr((I_D-UU^T)XX^T)\ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$$
**My second problem** is that I don't understand these equalities in (4). For `(*)` I get:
$$\underset{i}{\sum}||x_i-UU^Tx_i||^2=\underset{i}{\sum}x_i^T(I_D-UU^T)^2x_i$$
And the `(**)` I don't understand completely.

After substitution of `y` we obtain the optimization problem:
$$\underset{U}{max}\ Tr(UU^TXX^T)\ s.t.\ U^TU=I_d\ \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$
for which Lagrangian is:
$$L=Tr(U^TXX^TU)+Tr((I_d-U^TU)\Lambda)\ \ \ \ \ \ (6)$$
Differentiation with respect to `U` gives:
$$\Lambda=U^TXX^TU$$ 
And then in my lecture notes I have the following:

*From `(1)` and `(2)` the reconstruction error can be computed as:*
$$\epsilon=Tr((I_D-UU^T)XX^T)=\overset{D}{\sum}\lambda_i-\overset{d}{\sum}\lambda_i=\sum_{i=d+1}^{D}\lambda_i$$
So **my third question(s)** is why is this the error? Why eigenvalues of those eigenvectors that aren't included in a new low dimension represent an error? I would be glad to some intuitive explanation too.

I tried to read *Generalized Principal Component Analysis* by Vidal, Ma, Sastry but explanation there is a bit more generalized and doesn't differ much. I also tried to use *The Matrix Cookbook* to understand those matrix formulas but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks.